# How can I delete the n-th element in a list with javascsript

Tags: javascript

I know how to delete all elements from a list. I don't know how to delete just one item. Let's say I want to delete the 3th list item

of an unorder list . lets say I have the following:

```
          <ul id="parent">
    <li>
      <label>this is the fist item</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>this is the second item</label>
    </li>
    <li>
       <label>this is the third item</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>this is the fourth item</label>
    </li>
          </ul>
```

its eassy to delete the fist child or the last child. The list I am building gets built dynamicaly and it will be nice if I can delete the n-th child. It will be nice if I could do something like   document.getElementById("someElemet").delete

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var ul = document.getElementById('parent');
var liToKill = ul.childNodes[2];
liToKill.parentNode.removeChild( liToKill );
// or ul.removeChild( ... )
```

Answer (score 5):

Example code to remove the 3rd item (index number 2):

```
document.getElementById("parent").removeChild(document.getElementById("parent").children[2]);
```